# area and volume

Tags: functions, area

The total length of all 12 sides of a rectangular box is 60. (i) Write the possible values of the volume of the box. Your answer should be an interval. Now suppose in addition that the surface area of the box is given to be 56. Find, if you can, (ii) the length of the longest diagonal of the box (iii)the volume of box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $4(a+b+c)=60\iff a+b+c=15$

Now as $a,b,c>0;$  $$\dfrac{a+b+c}3\ge\sqrt[3]{abc}$$

$(ii)$

We have $2(ab+bc+ca)=56$

$$a^2+b^2+c^2=(a+b+c)^2-2(ab+bc+ca)$$

Now $$\dfrac{a^2+b^2+c^2}3\ge\sqrt[3]{a^2b^2c^2}$$

Comment: Why the downvotes? Maybe I am not familiar with math-meta, but it looks like the answer tries to give sufficient equations for the OP to deduce her answer. Unless the math.SX community doesn't like being asked homework questions?

Comment: @Sudhi _Particularly_ not homework/exam questions when OP doesn't produce any of their own work.  This is not a "solutions-on-demand" site.

Comment: @RecklessReckoner : I understand completely.

Comment: On the other hand, I don't know what the _specific_ reason for the downvote here is.

Comment: I am going to upvote the answer, but leave the question as it is. I like the answer :)